# How to show a userform an hide ONLY the Excel instance that contains the userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'd like to open a workbook and have only a particular userform show (and hide the workbook that contains the userform). I know how to open the form when the workbook opens, however my attempts at hiding ONLY this particular workbook has failed. I need the users to be able to work and/or open other Excel windows while using the userform. Any suggestions?
Thank you,
JP

I have tried the following methods:

```
myUserform.show vbModeless
Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
```

The above method doesn't seem to be consistand and acts funny if other Excel windows are currently open. I have also tried:

```
myUserform.show vbModeless
Application.Visible = False
```

This second method doesn't allow users to continue working on other Excel windows (which I need)

Comment: Why don't you 1. set a dummy sheet then 2. set the open event to select that sheet and 3. show the userform? 4. Finally, when userform is closed, close the WB

Comment: @Sgdva Because I don't want to see any sheets at all. I don't want to see Excel

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't set a dummy sheet in the WB that contains the Userform. By default, you cannot use a workbook with all sheets hidden. The only solutions are: use a dummy sheet which would contain nothing; use the personal workbook; or use a [workspace approach](https://superuser.com/questions/543315/use-excel-2010-macro-in-some-not-all-xlsx-workbooks)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The combined code below, isolates the instance of Excel that has the UserForm, forcing other files to open on another instance, and forcing you to open this file on its own instance. Allowing you to use `Application.Visible = False`

First you have to make sure that this instance of excel is only for the UserForm file.

When you open the workbook, make sure it's the only one on the instance.

ThisWorkbook Module:

```
'I'll explain why you need the App variable below
Private WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    If Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        'Not on its own instance
        Wb.Close False
    Else
        'Alright, it's the only workbook, lets open the form
        Set App = Application
        Application.Visible = False
        UserFormName.Show vbModeless
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

You may be thinking "Well this means I have to make sure I open this file before any other files or it wont work". This is true but you work around this by creating a shortcut to Excel, specify the "/X" parameter to open on a new instance, and the file. This way it will open on a new instance even if other files are open. In other words, find the EXCEL.exe, create a shortcut for it, and edit the target to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" /X "FilePath\FileName.xlsm"` The EXCEL Path may be different depending on your Excel version.

Now what happens if I try to open another excel file and it tries to open it on this instance? This is where the `App` variable comes into play. These next two subscripts are Event Handlers for whenever you try to open a file or a new workbook.

```
'On new blank Workbook Open
Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Set cwb = ThisWorkbook
    If Wb.Name <> cwb.Name Then
        Dim opFile As Variant
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.Close False
        opFile = Shell("EXCEL /X ", vbNormalFocus)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
'On File Workbook Open
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Set cwb = ThisWorkbook
    If Wb.Name <> cwb.Name Then
        Dim fDir As String, opFile As Variant
        fDir = Wb.Path & "\" & Wb.Name
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.Close False
        opFile = Shell("EXCEL /X """ & fDir & """", vbNormalFocus)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The new instance of excel becomes the "Windows preferred" so any new workbooks you open will try to open in the new instance, leaving the UserForm one alone. And done, this file should always be on its own instance, if you try to open another file or a new workbook, they should open in a new instance with those handlers.

Note: Some event handlers get activated when you open the file, if you make any changes to the code you may need to Save and reopen the file for them to work properly.